# "Duplicate" methods in a Kotlin class

Tags: kotlin

Trying to get my head around why this isn't at least a warning in Kotlin

I had a class with methods similar to this and it came back to bite me:

```
class TestDuplicates {
    fun doSomething() {
        print("doSomething()")
    }
    fun doSomething(optional: String = "") {        
        print("doSomething($optional)")
    }
}

fun main() {    
    // Which is called? Why not at least warning?
    TestDuplicates().doSomething()
}
```

Why is this allowed in Kotlin or why is it not at least a warning as there is obvious confusion on a developers side if not the compilers side. In hind sight I should not have defined my class this way, but a warning would have been very helpful in this scenario.

Comment: By normal overload resolution rules (at least in most languages with overloading), there isn't a warning if there is more than one applicable method so far as there is one most specific one. Kotlin apparently considers the method without parameters to be more specific in this case, which makes sense.

Comment: Have you found any solution?

Comment: No solution, boils down to verifying my understanding, this is a language definition "issue", as designed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we decompile it to Java bytecode this is what we get:

```
public final class TestDuplicates {
public final void doSomething(@NotNull String optional) {
  Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull(optional, "optional");
  String var2 = "doSomething(" + optional + ")";
  System.out.print(var2);
}

// $FF: synthetic method

public static void doSomething$default(TestDuplicates var0, String var1, int var2,  Object var3) {
  if ((var2 & 1) != 0) {
     var1 = "";
  }
  var0.doSomething(var1);
}

public final void doSomething() {
  String var1 = "doSomething()";
  System.out.print(var1);
 }
}
```

Apparently, the compiler generates a synthetic method where it checks the condition if the method you chose was supplied with a non-default value, if not it invokes `var1 = "doSomething()";`, which is your method without the default parameter.

As for why is not there a warning? It's because you know what you are typing and the compiler is cool with it because it knows a base condition to fall on.

**Decompiled Main**

```
 public final class MainKt {
 public static final void main() {
   (new TestDuplicates()).doSomething();
}

 // $FF: synthetic method
 public static void main(String[] var0) {
   main();
 }
}
```

To tackle name ambiguity, the compiler generates a synthetic method for additional checking. This statement can be proven if you remove the default value and then decompile again.

```
class TestDuplicates {

 fun doSomething() {
    print("doSomething()")
 }

 fun doSomething(optional: String) { //Removed default value
    print("doSomething($optional)")
 }
}
```

**After decompilation:**

```
public final class TestDuplicates {

 public final void doSomething() {
  String var1 = "doSomething()";
  boolean var2 = false;
  System.out.print(var1);
}

 public final void doSomething(@NotNull String optional) {
  Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull(optional, "optional");
  String var2 = "doSomething(" + optional + ')';
  boolean var3 = false;
  System.out.print(var2);
 }
}
```

The compiler did not generate an additional method for ambiguity check, now it's solely up to the programmer which method to invoke.

Comment: You may know what you are typing, but you could _mean_ one of two different things by it; and that sort of ambiguity is something the compiler really ought to flag up.  — Also, I don't think your bytecode answers the question; it would need the decompilation of the `main()` method too.

Comment: Decompiled `main()` does not really bring anything useful to the table. The real deal is `doSomething$default` method. Would the compiler still care about flagging the ambiguity if it internally checks if the method was supplied with a non-default parameter or not? The compiler generates an addition synthetic method for such ambiguity, if you remove the default parameter, then the compiler does not generate this synthetic method.